# .gitignore pattern format ** doesn't work

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm trying to ignore some folders in my .gitignore with the specific pattern format `/**/` (I found the docs here : http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) like this :

```
src/**/Entity/*.php~
```

But when I do a `git status` in the terminal, It return to me this:

```
Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/CapturePhotoVideo.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/CodeReconnaissanceVocale.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/CodeTraduction.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/DetailTransaction.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/Langue.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/Media.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/MediaLangue.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/Offre.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/QualiteVideo.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/SousTitre.php~
#       src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/Transaction.php~
#       web/images/logo_black.svg
```

Or each folder in `src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/....php~` shouldn't appear ...

But if in my .gitignore I replace le line `src/**/Entity/*.php~` by this line `src/AVC/MediasBundle/Entity/*.php~` everything works good !

Why doesn't the pattern format `**` work here?

Comment: This looks like it should work. What version of Git do you have (`git --version`)? Is there any reason you couldn't simply ignore all files ending in `~`, e.g. `*~`? That's a very common ignore pattern, since such files are usually temporary.

Comment: the version is 1.7.10.4 ! When I push the commit from PhpStorm, I just don't want to upload temporary files on my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ignore pattern in your question works as expected for me with Git 2.1.0. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.

Your version of Git is quite old (the source code seems to have been [released mid-2012](https://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.10.4.tar.gz)). It is probably worth upgrading to the latest version that is available for your operating system and seeing if that fixes things.

> I just don't want to upload temporary files on my repository.

In this case I would advise a simpler pattern:

```
*~
```

This very common ignore pattern simply ignores all files ending in `~`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in a test repo, and this works for me:

.gitignore

```
src/**/*.php~
```

My guess would be that adding the extra directory with a double `*` is causing some issues.

Comment: humm... strange... I have the 1.7.10.4 version of git ! and you ?